How to test Google's OAuth granular consent screen
We received a notice from Google "OAuth clients must support granular consent, starting June 17, 2024" which indicates they are moving to a granular consent screen giving user's the ability to manage permissions on a granular level.
I tried reading through their documentation, but it, sadly, is byzantine and not clear. And there is no option for support other than for Google to abuse StackOverflow and funnel support to here. :(
OAuth app registrations in Google don't specify scopes (as far as I can tell). To my knowledge, the application may request scopes at runtime. The documentation does say that if you are just using "sign in scopes", then granular permissions will not be shown which is all we are doing.
If we no longer request anything other than sign-in scopes, then is any action necessary here? Is there a way to have an OAuth app registration opt-in to this new functionality, so we can test it?

do you find any solution to this issue?

You can go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent to see what scopes your application requests. Click "EDIT APP" -> "SAVE AND CONTINUE" -> You should be on the Scopes page. However, it is just a reference. At the end of the day, it is up to your code on what scopes are requesting.
To test your application, see how to enable granular permissions in this section.
If your applications only request Sign-In scopes, then this change should not affect your application.

That link is super helpful, thank you!

@hermz, May I ask you one question?
My Android app only use GoogleSignIn.getClient() and GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2() to request Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE) sign-in and Google Drive access. The granular permission should not affect my Android app, right?

Hi, the granular permission rollout would affect Android app. Best practice is not requesting all scopes (Sign-in and non-Sign-in scopes) at once. Ideally, you should request Sign-in scopes when signing in your users. You should only request the DRIVE_FILE scope when users need to access the features needed the Drive scope. In this case, users wouldn't see the granular permissions consent screen.
